# Evaluating Prefix expressions with multiple stacks

Tags: java, stack, prefix

I require assistance in pushing Strings to stacks.

For my assignment, I will be evaluating prefix expressions and we are required to use a stack to keep track of the sub-expressions as they are evaluated and the operands that have yet to be evaluated.

The main issue I am having is getting the "+" and "*" to push to a `Stack<String>`. I have tried multiple methods with no success at all.

Please see sample I/O and code. I have made comments by the methods in question. The first chuck of comments near the top of the code were notes for myself as I would step away from the computer from time to time.

Sample I/O:

```
{Please enter a prefix expression: + 2 51
Popping Integers Stack:
2 
51 
Popping Operators Stack:
*nothing shows here*
```

Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test211
{
    /* create two stacks, one for operators and one for integers
     * accept user input as a string with space as delimiter use a tokenizer 
     * use If statement to determine if token is integer or
     * operator and pop each integer/operator into a variable
     * use operator pop and If statement to determine order of operations
     * possible use of counters to help determine order of operations
     * 
     * 
     * set input to arraylist then tokenize to seperate into 2 stacks
     */

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        tokenizer();
    }


    /*This method is supposed to take the user input and separate it into
     * tokens. Once separated, I am currently sending the tokens through 2 different methods
     * to establish my operand stacks and operator stacks
     */

    private static void tokenizer()
    {
        Stack<String> operators = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<Integer> integers = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<String> expression = new Stack<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        String user = userInput();
        tokens = tokeniseInput(user);

        /*The next three methods convert my input string into a Stack<String>
         * and pass that Stack<String> to two methods to separate the
         * operators and operands 
         */

        expression = buildStack(tokens);
        integers = operatorSeparator(expression);
        operators = operandSeparator(expression);
        System.out.println("Popping Integers Stack:");
        for (Integer i : integers)
        {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Popping Operators Stack:");
        for (String s : operators)
        {
            System.out.println(s + " ");
        }

    }



    private static void evaluator(Stack<String> operators, Stack<Integer> integers)
    {

        int result;
        if(operators.empty())
        {
            result = integers.pop();
            System.out.println("Result: " + result + " only printed if operator stack was empty.");
        }

        else if (operators.peek() == "+")
        {
            int x = integers.pop();
            int y = integers.pop();
            result = x + y;
            System.out.println("Result: " + result + " only printed if operator stack next was +.");
        }

        else if (operators.peek() == "*")
        {
            if (operators.empty())
            {
                result = integers.pop() * integers.pop();
                System.out.println("Result: " + result + " only printed if operator stack next was * and then stack empty");
            }
        }
    }


    private static String userInput()
    {
        String input;       
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
        System.out.print("Please enter a prefix expression: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
        return input;
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> tokeniseInput(String u)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrString = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(u);
        while(str.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String s = str.nextToken();
                arrString.add(s);
            }

        return arrString;
    }

    public static Stack<Integer> buildIntStack(ArrayList<String> arrString)
    {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        for(int i=arrString.size()-1; i>=0;i--)
        {
            if (!arrString.equals("+") || !arrString.equals("*"))
            {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(arrString.get(i));
                stack.push(temp);
            }

        }   
        return stack;   
    }


    public static Stack<String> buildStrStack(ArrayList<String> arrString)
    {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        for(int i=arrString.size()-1; i>=0;i--)
        {
            if (arrString.equals("+") || arrString.equals("*"))
            {
                stack.push(arrString.get(i));
            }
        }
        return stack;   
    }


    /*Method to take input string and convert to Stack<String>
     */
    public static Stack<String> buildStack(ArrayList<String> arrString)
    {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        for(int i=arrString.size()-1; i>=0;i--)
        {
            stack.push(arrString.get(i));
        }   
        return stack;   
    }

    /*Method to separate operational symbols from integers 
     */
    public static Stack<String> operandSeparator(Stack<String> stack)
    {
        Stack<String> temp = new Stack<String>();   
        while (!stack.empty())
        {
            String popped = stack.pop();
            if(popped.compareTo("+") == 0)
            {
                temp.push("+");
            }
            else if(popped.compareTo("*") == 0)
            {
                temp.push("*");
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    /*Method to separate integers from operational symbols 
     */
    public static Stack<Integer> operatorSeparator(Stack<String> stack)
    {
        Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<Integer>();
        while (!stack.empty())
        {
            String popped = stack.pop();            
            if(!(popped.compareTo("+") == 0 || popped.compareTo("*")==0))
            {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(popped);
                temp.push(x);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the line integers = operatorSeparator(expression); the expression stack is empty. Also, are you sure you need to use that many stacks and move the data several times from stack to stack?

Why not use a more simple approach. This for example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

class Prefix {
  static List<Object> tokenize(String input) {
    ArrayList<Object> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s: input.split("\\s+")) {
      try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        tokens.add(d);
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        tokens.add(s);
      }
    }
    return tokens;
  }

  static double eval(List<Object> expr) {
    Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<>();
    for(int i = expr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      Object o = expr.get(i);
      if(o instanceof Double) {
        stack.push((Double)o);
      } else if(o.equals("+")) {
        stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());
      } else if(o.equals("*")) {
        stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop());
      }
    }
    return stack.pop();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> tokens = tokenize("* + 3.2 4.7 + 5 6");
    System.out.println(tokens);
    System.out.println(eval(tokens));
  }
}
```

Comment: as I stated, the assignment requires the use of 2 stacks: one to total the sub expressions and one to to keep track of the operators that have yet to be used.